# Using MasterPage disadvantages

Tags: asp.net, .net, session, master-pages

We can use MasterPage for integrating the layout of the header and footer for example.

But we can use it for Server Sides operations like checking Session for user login.
Is this method risky? What are the disadvantages if we are using this method?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we should check session for user login manually in code. ASP.NET provides us with Forms Authentication which already does that for us. Authentication is another concern that should not be mixed with page logic (separation of concerns)

Answer (score 0):

There is no disadvantages in the Session using master pages. Otherwise it helps checking session values, as no need to check the values at every page. It can be checked only in master page and will effect on all the pages.

Comment: if we put that logic into master page, how to deal with case when they want to reuse the header and footer of master page but want the page to be public? (no session checking)

Comment: Can u pls more explain this, "reuse the header and footer of master page but want the page to be public"

Comment: the master page has footer and header, they want all pages in their site to be consistent, so all pages use master page. But some of them are public pages (no authentication required), some of them need users to be logged in.

Comment: For above situation, you will have to put logic under Page_Load of Master Page. Put hiddenfield in the master page, set this hiddenfield value to 1 in all the page where authentication is not required then put a check inside page_load of master page if this value is set 1 then no session check other wise session should be checked.

Comment: then logic of page_load will be applied to all pages using the master page. It means they all check for user session, you have to somehow override that logic for public pages (not separation of concerns)

Comment: User Sessio will be checked only once in the master according to value set. This value must be set under page load of all unauthorized pages.

Comment: yes, that's a trick. We can trick it to work but that's not a good code design.

Comment: that's why asp.net provides another mechanism (Forms authentication) that is separate from page logic.

Comment: Then You will hv to use form authentication and folder wise security from web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Master pages can be used to check whether session exists of a authenticated user of no else redirect the user to login screen.

On login screen try using ASP.NET login controls.